# Can I create custom tests or actions, JUST for merge_group?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a set of tests that run on normal PR which is perfectly fine.  Those actions are all required in the Github branch protection settings.   What I wanted to do during MERGE QUEUE pipeline add an item that is specifically required to that.

I have been looking all over, and While i was noticing that ALL required items will be checked, i cant create a "required" item JUST for the Merge Group itself.

Pretty much, I was trying to create some external URL checks that need to pass but i couldnt figure out how to do it.

```
develop --------------------------------------->
                          / MG ONLY Checks
                         / PR/MG Checks
branch ----/ PR Checks -/
```

Instead of creating Conditionals to run or not in the github yaml, I was curious if there is something similar in Concourse, so i guess I could create a webhook that runs on Push/PR/MergeQueue, but add a conditional for it to run?   Maybe I could instead encapsulate this in a github action instead of it being a settings defined Webhook.  I think that could be decent too.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have searched far and wide and my conclusion is as of November 2023, it is not possible to have a separate required checks for Merge Queue. There is an inactive discussion here https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/47548

Comment: I saw the same thing. Which actually makes sense if you think about it.  You can however add TO the merge_queue checks by adding more actions, but you will need to at minimum keep those that exist on the PR.

I could have 3 different branches with 3 different PR rulesets, but the Merge_queue will have ALL 3 rulesets union together.